# i want my shell script to generate a file with the output in it

Tags: html, bash, macos, shell

so basically, instead of writing over and over again the html code for a website i am building (install page so i need one for each app i offer to download)so i made this script. i want the output to be in a file generated so, on the console it asks what should i name the file (e.g: hi.html) and the output will be in that file in an specific directory on my mac.

```
# prompt for input.
APP=$1
if [ -z "${APP}" ]
then
    read -p "App: " APP
fi

REPORT=$2
if [ -z "${REPORT}" ]
then
    read -p "Report App: " REPORT
fi

APPICON=$3
if [ -z "${APPICON}" ]
then
    read -p "AppIcon: " APPICON
fi

PLISTURL=$4
if [ -z "${PLISTURL}" ]
then
    read -p "plist URL: " PLISTURL
fi

DESCRIPTION=$5
if [ -z "${DESCRIPTION}" ]
then
    read -p "Description: " DESCRIPTION
fi

VERSION=$6
if [ -z "${VERSION}" ]
then
    read -p "Version: " VERSION
fi

DEV=$7
if [ -z "${DEV}" ]
then
    read -p "Developer: " DEV
fi
# Generate the P-List
read -r -d '' HTML << EndOfHTML
================================================================================

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <!-- Your app title -->
    <title>My App</title>
    <!-- Path to Framework7 iOS CSS theme styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.ios.min.css">
    <!-- Path to Framework7 iOS related color styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">
    <!-- Path to your custom app styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Status bar overlay for full screen mode (PhoneGap) -->
    <div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>

    <!-- Views -->
    <div class="views">
      <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
      <div class="view view-main">
        <!-- Top Navbar-->
        <div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="left"><a href="index.html" class="back link"> <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
    <div class="center sliding">$APP</div>
    <div class="right"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fabout.twitter.com%2Fes%2Fresources%2Fbuttons&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&related=ItsNash0&screen_name=TweakBoxApp&text=$REPORT%20does%20not%20work!&tw_p=tweetbutton" class="link external">Report App</a></div>
  </div>
</div>



        <!-- Pages container, because we use fixed-through navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
        <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
          <!-- Page, "data-page" contains page name -->
          <div data-page="index" class="page">
            <!-- Scrollable page content -->
            <div class="page-content">
              <!-- Content Here-->
     <img src="appicons/$APPICON" class="appinstallicon"/>

     <a class="button button-big button-round active installbutton link external" href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=$PLISTURL"><b>1. Install App!</b></a>

     <a class="button button-big button-round active installbutton link external" href="prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME"><b>2. Change Date!</b></a>

     <div class="content-block-title">Description</div>
        <div class="content-block tablet-inset">
      <div class="content-block-inner">
        <p>$DESCRIPTION</p>
        <ul>
        <li>Name: $APP</li>
        <li>Version: $VERSION</li>
        <li>Developer: $DEV</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


            <!-- Content Here-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bottom Toolbar-->

            <!-- Toolbar links -->

    <!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Path to your app js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
================================================================================

EndOfHTML

# WHAT TO DO WITH THE OUTPUT.
OUTPUT=$8
if [ -z "${OUTPUT}" ]
then
    echo "$HTML"
else
    echo "$HTML" >> $OUTPUT
fi
```

So i dont know how to write in bash to create a file( which i want to name) in an specific directory with the output in it

Comment: What is your question

Comment: I edited, my question is at the end

Comment: You have tried `echo "$HTML" >> $OUTPUT` which does puts the contents of `$HTML` in file `$OUTPUT`. Does not that work?

Comment: @Fazlin that just outputs to the console, i want it to output to a new file which i want to be name-customizable

Comment: It may be because your `$8` is empty and hence it reaches the `if [ -z "${OUTPUT}" ]` condition wherein you have done just `echo "$HTML"`

Comment: Show us how you run the scripts with the arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you want to shovel a string into a file. You can do so in two different ways.

The first way to do this would be with a string:

```
# Here we put the filename which is a string into the variable $FILENAME.
$FILENAME = "foo.html"

# Given that you have built your HTML string and 
# put it into a variable called $HTML.
# We can then redirect the output of echoing 
# our $HTML variable to our $FILENAME variable.
echo $HTML >> $FILENAME
```

The second way would be using an argument you pass to the script:

```
# Here $1 contains the first argument you can pass when running a bash script.
# For example if you ran `bash myscript.sh foo.html` $1 would then contain
# a string "foo.html".
# This will allow you to dynamically generate the file name without having 
# to edit your script.
$FILENAME = $1
echo $HTML >> $FILENAME
```

ie. `bash myscript.sh foo.html`

Comment: i dont really understand this. my understanding of bash is very limited

Comment: i cants seem to understand what you guys are telling me. i tried this

Comment: i can see where you are going here. so based on the script i uploaded, what should i add to to the second way, and where should it add it.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I wsnt my script to, instead of output to the console, create a new file with the html code in it. Also i want to be able to tell the script what i want to name that html file

Comment: My script is based on one i found online, i reverse engineered it so now it servers a useful purpose for me, but it was set to output to the console. I have absolutely no idea how to write bash, i just modified the script based on logic

Comment: I don't understand how my answer does not exactly answer that question for you.

Comment: i kinda understand that you are telling me how to make a veriable where i can write the name of the file i want to make

Comment: Do you want to continue this in chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/117719/bash-script-help?tab=general

Comment: and then you unaccept my answer -_- why do I even waste my time?

Comment: i need a simpler explanation :/ :v

Comment: Go into your terminal, literally type the following `echo "<body>hello world</body>" >> mysite.html`. This site is not for general teaching of programming languages. This is a Question and Answer site. 1 question 1 answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the filename as the 8th argument. As 0th argument is your script filename containing the script. As @Fazlin pointed out showing the entire commandline you are using would tell if you are missing something.

if the above script is contained in a file called GenerateHtml.sh your commandline should look like:

```
GenerateHtml.sh "app" "report" "appicon" "plisturl" "description" "version" "dev" "[output].htm"
```

Here [output] is the name of the html file.